# PHP regular expression last address of url web link

Tags: php, regex

I've read multiple tutorials on regex but it just won't stick in my head. I can never get my patterns to work. Hope someone can help.

I have a php variable ($content) where I need to find a certain pattern that looks like this

http://localhost/Foodraveller/assets/images/upload/resize_image/fd1bf6aa02d5c39563c30b5035013141.jpg

I would like to search:

- I want "fd1bf6aa02d5c39563c30b5035013141.jpg" the last address of URL link

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Nothing tried so far, I assume

Comment: php:- `$data = explode('/',$link_string); echo $data[count($data)-1];`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
.*\/(.*)
```

You get the data in capture group 1

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Bc4Jdk/3)

1. `.*`  matches any character (except for line terminators)
2. `\/` matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
3. 1st Capturing Group `(.*)` where `.*` matches any character (except for line
   terminators)

Sample Code

```
$re = '/.*\/(.*)/';
$str = 'http://localhost/Foodraveller/assets/images/upload/resize_image/fd1bf6aa02d5c39563c30b5035013141.jpg';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0];
```

[Run it here](http://ideone.com/PnNOtW)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest pattern to use would be:

```
/([^\/?&]*)$/
```

Explanation:

`( )` is a capture group, stating you want to capture what matches the pattern inside.

`[ ]` defines a character set to match.  Using `^` inside means "not" these characters. I specified `/` (escaped of course) as well as `?` and `&` (which are used to signify HTTP URI parameters) to say "match any characters that are not a forward-slash, ampersand or question mark."

`*` is a quantifier meaning "0 or more repeating."

Lastly, the `$` used at the end of the pattern means "anchor to the end of the string."

This pattern would match anything at the end of a URI that represents a filename with parameters.  If you want only the filename without parameters, I would recommend using:

```
/([^\/?&]*)(?:\?[^?]*)?$/
```

Explanation of the extra pattern:

`(?:  )` is a non-capture group, used to specify a pattern.  This is useful when you want to add a quantifier to it.  I used a `?` at the end, meaning that the pattern can occur "0 or 1 times."

`[^?]*` means "match anything that is not a question mark 0 or more times."

This pattern will match URLs such as the following:

```
http://www.example.com/  (no captured filename)
http://www.example.com/file.js (capturing "file.js")
http://www.example.com/?q=something  (no captured filename)
http://www.example.com/file.js?q=something  (capturing "file.js")
```

Also, a really good regex tester is available at http://www.regex101.com/.  It supports perl/php, Python, Javascript and Go.

Here is a link of the last regex in action:  https://www.regex101.com/r/IwhSBr/1
Although on the right, it will say that the pattern is matching on not just the filename *and* the parameter, each match should state that "Group 1" contains the filename or nothing.

Comment: works, but @Maverick_Mrt's answer is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

see a working demo herehttp://phpfiddle.org/main/code/47jt-38y2

```
<?php
$url="http://localhost/Foodraveller/assets/images/upload/resize_image/fd1bf6aa02d5c39563c30b5035013141.jpg";
$url=preg_replace('/(.)*\//',"",$url);
echo $url;

?>
```